# How stop multiple retrofit calls when using it with Rx-Java used in search functionality for android?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I have a search functionality in my Android app. The searchView has callback `onSearchTextChanged(String oldQuery, String newQuery)`. This callback function calls every time user enters any text to search field. I have a REST call in this callback which is triggering every time each word is being typed. Which leads to multiple calls for REST. I want to avoid that. I just want only one instance active at a time which is latest one and all other calls should be canceled instantly whenever the new letter is typed. Below are code details.

```
 @Override
    public void onSearchTextChanged(String oldQuery, String newQuery) {

        floatingSearchView.showProgress();
        moviesAPI.searchQuery(newQuery)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Search>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onCompleted() {
                                   Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted() called");
                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                   Log.d(TAG, "onError() called with: e = [" + e + "]");
                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onNext(Search search) {
                                   floatingSearchView.hideProgress();
                                   floatingSearchView.swapSuggestions(search.getSearchResults());
                                   Log.d(TAG, "onNext() called with: search = [" + search + "]");
                               }
                           }

                );

    }
```

Comment: What if instead you put a few second delay after each character typed to actually start the request? Then you're not sending for every letter when the user types more.

Comment: As stated in the below answer you probably need debounce operator. Take a look @ https://github.com/ragdroid/rxify. Run the app and look for Library which shows search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use debounce to delay search requests while typing (and only after user stops typing for x duration).

Additionally, for canceling older requests when new request arrive you may transform the text changes events to stream of event (either manually or using library like RxBindings), and then switchMap each new text event to query.
switchMap operator will cancel previous request that still going, when new request arrive driven by new search text stream.

you can found various examples of implementing search suggestions for android with rxjava, like this one by Kaushik Gopal: [instantauto-searching-text-listeners-using-subjects--debounce](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/blob/master/README.md#3-instantauto-searching-text-listeners-using-subjects--debounce)

code sample, this sample uses [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) library for easily getting textChanages events as Observable stream.

```
RxTextView.textChangeEvents(tv)
                .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .switchMap(new Func1<TextViewTextChangeEvent, Observable<SearchResult>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<SearchResult> call(
                            TextViewTextChangeEvent textViewTextChangeEvent) {
                        return moviesAPI.searchQuery(textViewTextChangeEvent.text().toString())
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<SearchResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted() called");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        floatingSearchView.hideProgress();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onError() called with: e = [" + e + "]");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(SearchResult search) {
                        floatingSearchView.hideProgress();
                        floatingSearchView.swapSuggestions(search.getSearchResults());
                        Log.d(TAG, "onNext() called with: search = [" + search + "]");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: So I did like [this](https://gist.github.com/asbadve/b3445231a5a46bfb5bb2e3ed8b29ef29.js") but no success. Can you help me with some code.The link you gave me not having any sample code.

Comment: in your example you started from the query obsevable, the source of events here is text changes stream of events, then you need to debounce it with number value and time unit (ignore all events while there is no delay of X between them), and not a function, then you should switchMap each emission of the text changes event to a server query, and finally subscribe and handle result, added sample code in the answer

Comment: I am using third party lib for search view how can i convert those view to observable?

Comment: you can take a look at RxBinding code:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/280882b29ac85861885df9880f65655ea4a31464/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/widget/TextViewTextChangeEventObservable.java
or more generally on how to wrap async call with RxJava:
https://medium.com/yammer-engineering/converting-callback-async-calls-to-rxjava-ebc68bde5831#.cplx3chdy
the short answer is to create Observable using Observable.fromEmitter (or not recommended anymore create method), there register and listen to textview events and emit onNext with each event

Comment: @Ajinkya if it was helpful, please accept my answer